# Qt (c++) - Is it possible to use a signal to return from a method?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on an application that takes an image and takes measurements and draws to the image. This is all done in a method that consists of several steps that involve user input from the mouse. This method is called using a pushbutton on the toolbar.

I am wondering if it is possible to return from this function before it is finished executing. It seems logical that if the pushbutton is pressed halfway through execution of these steps, it will "cancel" the first instance and start a new instance of these steps. Or to put it differently, how would one simply cancel execution of this method?

The one way that I can think to do this would be to use the signal to set a flag to and check that flag after each step is executed. If the flag == true, then return. It seems like there should be a better way to do this as opposed to several if statements.

Comment: i believed you can send pointer to function while you calling the signal...

Comment: Why do not you try to divide the method a few methods and at when one method has finished doing what's doing it starts the followinf method only if someone has not cancelled the job.

Comment: That is certainly more elegant, but I have to wonder if there is a way to interrupt and cancel execution. @Proxytype, are you able to elaborate a little?

Comment: There is a chain responsibility pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern, before moving to next successor you can check flag

Comment: A little more research has me thinking Qthread is the way to go.

Comment: i dont have environment here but this is good place to start : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html, if you want to cancel execution when signal fired add a global flag for canceling operation and check if it true and return from function... also very important to work with threads in this cases...

Comment: Glib has a [GCancellable](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GCancellable.html) class just for situations like this. You could build something similar in Qt, but unfortunately there's nothing like it built in.

Comment: QFuture is cancellable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this using threads, other issue is to stop it. You may check it before execution of each process step ...
So example implementation may look like this ? Worker executes steps ( timer simulates some action ) in its own thread. If start is invoked again, steps chain is replaced by new one. Other problem is what to do with current steps being replaced but this is another issue.

```
class Step
{
public:
    virtual ~Step() {}
    void setNextStep( Step* next )
    {
        successor = next;
    }
    Step* nextStep()
    {
        return successor;
    }

    virtual void process() = 0;

private:
    Step* successor;
};

class Step1 : public Step
{
    virtual void process()
    {
        std::cout << "Step1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Step2 : public Step
{
    virtual void process()
    {
        std::cout << "Step2" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Step3 : public Step
{
    virtual void process()
    {
        std::cout << "Step3" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker( QObject* parent = 0 ) : QObject( parent ), timer( this )
    {
        QObject::connect( &timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(work()));
    }
public slots:
    void start()
    {
        Step1* fStep = new Step1();
        Step2* sStep = new Step2();
        Step3* tStep = new Step3();
        fStep->setNextStep( sStep );
        sStep->setNextStep( tStep );
        currentStep = fStep;
        if( !timer.isActive() )
        {
            timer.start( 1 );
        }
    }

    void work()
    {
        currentStep->process();
        currentStep = currentStep->nextStep();
        if( !currentStep )
        {
            std::cout << "finished";
            timer.stop();
            //test one run emit
            emit quit();
        }
    }

    void stop()
    {
        std::cout << "stop" << std::endl;
        timer.stop();
        emit quit();
    }

signals:
    void quit();

private:
    QTimer timer;
    Step* currentStep;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    QCoreApplication a( argc, argv );
    Worker* worker = new Worker();
    QThread* thread = new QThread();
    worker->moveToThread( thread );
    QObject::connect( thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(start()) );
    QObject::connect( thread, SIGNAL(finished()), &a, SLOT(quit()) );
    QObject::connect( worker, SIGNAL(quit()), thread, SLOT(quit()) );

    QTimer::singleShot( 0, thread, SLOT(start(Priority)));

    return a.exec();
}
```

BTW this poc is one great memory leak :)